# Bootstrap 4 lower screen size ordering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is how my page looks like (roughly):

```
<div class="container new-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 info">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 contact-form">
    ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have my info area on the left, and my contact form on the right side. Then when I resize my screen to preview how it would look like on the mobile(or lower screen size).

The info area is on one row and contact-from is on the second row, which is expected behavior.

My design looks different thought, it assumes contact-form to come first and then info area to be below.

Is there a css property or some way that I can keep my current layout to achieve this element arrangement? (on lower screen resolutions only)

Comment: Can you add the col-xs-* also to the class.

Comment: @Mukesh Keshu I added col-xs-12 to both of them, so they occupy full width of the screen. But they're still not arranged the way I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap 4 you can use `order` class.

```
<div class="container new-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 order-sm-2 info">
    ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 order-sm-1 contact-form">
    ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

In case you are using bootstrap 3, you can use `col-sm-pull-*` or `col-sm-push-*`.

Reference - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-column-ordering